# DOM Beginner Navigation problems

Tags: javascript, html

in this code, I'm simply trying to target the last li tag within the second unordered list and replace the text from 'balsamic vinegar' to 'kale', print the text content of the last item to the p tag - 'stuff' , as well as change add the attribute of class = "cool" to it.

Currently just practicing and getting a feeling of DOM navigation here, any help would be appreciated

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    #items li {
      width: 400px;
      list-style: none;
      padding: 10px 0px;
      border-top: 1px solid black;
      border-bottom: 1px solid black;
      border-right: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    .cool {
      background-color: aqua;
    }
    
    .hot {
      background-color: crimson;
    }
    
    .warm {
      background-color: green;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="navContainer">
      <ul id="sideBar">
        <a href="LandingPage.html">
          <li>Home</li>
        </a>
        <li id="dropdown">Applications
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="CalculatorPageApp.html">Simple Calculator</a>
            <a href="ToDoListApp.html">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </div>
          <li>
            <a href="Survey.html">
              <li>Survey</li>
            </a>
            <a href="Calendar.html">
              <li>Calendar</li>
            </a>
            <a href="Contact.html">
              <li>Contact Us</li>
            </a>
      </ul>
      <!--- end of sidebar -->
    </div>
    <!--- end of side container -->
    <h1 id="header">List King</h1>
    <h2>Buy groceries</h2>
    <ul id="items">
      <li id="one" class="hot"><em>fresh</em>figs</li>
      <li id="two" class="hot">pine nuts</li>
      <li id="three" class="hot">honey</li>
      <li id="four">balsamic vinegar</li>
    </ul>
    <p id="thing">hi</p>
  </div>
  <!---End wrapper --->
  <script>
    var stuff = document.getElementById('thing');
    var startItem = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[1];
    var lastItem = startItem.lastChild;
    var text = lastItem.nodeValue;
    stuff.textContent = text;

    text.replace('balsamic vinegar', 'kale');
    
    lastItem.setAttribute('class','cool');
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use the error messages - they're there to help you! See how if you run your code snippet, it says `lastItem.setAttribute is not a function`. Since we know `setAttribute` is a real function, maybe something's wrong with `lastItem`. So step one to debug: try adding `console.log(lastItem)` right after you declare that var, and see what it returns.

Comment: try `lastElementChild` instead of `lastChild`

Comment: Note that *lastChild* may be an element, text node, comment, etc. Text nodes do not implement element API methods like *setAttribute*.

Comment: Yup I changed it to lastElementChild from lastChild, why does that work?
Also changed stuff.textContent with stuff.innerHTML, and that made it print out correctly, still not too sure, going to have to read up more on this

Answer (score 0):

Document.getElementById("items").childNode[3].setAttribute("class","cool");
That should work to change class attribute